# Connecting to a private IP over WiFi and public IP over LTE simultaneously

Tags: 4g, termux

I'm designing an Ubuntu app for Android which is running through a Termux chroot jail. The app requires the phone to be connected to a drone through the drone's generated Wifi network. This network does not provide internet access (obviously). Unfortunately, I still need the app to have general internet access while connected to the drone network. This means I need to be able to designate certain address accesses to use LTE and others to use Wifi. Any idea how to set this up from within the chroot jail (or externally)?

Note: I saw a question similar to this one answered 4 years back. However, it doesn't seem like an up-to-date answer was provided. Here's the [post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/157580/can-the-nexus-6p-use-gsm-data-if-the-connected-wifi-has-no-route-to-the-internet).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There's a similar situation asked recently: [Unable to communicate to a local WiFi with mobile data enabled](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232561/44325). The linked questions on there also explain the difficulty of supporting this on Android devices.

Comment: What if you would run the phone in AP mode, and so you would contact the drone? You can identify the drone by its MAC (more hardcore would be to use some zeroconf solution like bonjour).